# How to SUM two results in sql query and SUM the results into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum the two results from my sql query, and the result of the sum will be used again to sum the second sql query

**SQL SERVER**

**FIRST SQL SERVER QUERY**

```
SELECT  b.paytype, CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(SUM(b.principal) AS money), 1) as 'Cash Sales'
FROM fin_tbl_crjhead  a 
INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjlot b 
    ON a.uid = b.headuid
left JOIN fin_tbl_crjsundries c ON b.headuid = c.uid
WHERE a.ordate BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31'
  AND a.brcode = '010'
GROUP BY b.paytype
ORDER BY b.paytype ASC
```

I got the results right, but i cant sum the two results:

[image]

**Second SQL Server Query**

```
SELECT SUM(a.credit)
  FROM [TFINANCE].[dbo].[fin_tbl_crjsundries] a INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjlot b 
on a.headuid = b.headuid INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjhead c ON c.uid = b.headuid
  where a.acctcode = '100 200-02' and a.brcode = '010' and c.ordate
 between '2018-12-01' and '2018-12-31'
```

The result of the second query is `2783.07`
now I want to add fp + installment + `2783.07`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server

Comment: a, b and c are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, e.g. ch for fin_tbl_crjhead  and cl for  fin_tbl_crjlot.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for your suggestion, but kindly please proceed to my answer

Comment: Show us the expected result as well. And matching table data would be great. All as formatted text, not images. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See updated question, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sum( CASE WHEN paytype IN ('fp', 'installment') THEN b.principal ELSE 0 
       END ) 
       + (SELECT Sum(a.credit) 
          FROM   [TFINANCE].[dbo].[fin_tbl_crjsundries] a 
                 INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjlot b 
                         ON a.headuid = b.headuid 
                 INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjhead c 
                         ON c.uid = b.headuid 
          WHERE  a.acctcode = '100 200-02' 
                 AND a.brcode = '010' 
                 AND c.ordate BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31') 
FROM   (SELECT b.paytype, 
               Cast(Sum(b.principal) AS MONEY) AS 'Cash Sales' 
        FROM   fin_tbl_crjhead a 
               INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjlot b 
                       ON a.uid = b.headuid 
               LEFT JOIN fin_tbl_crjsundries c 
                      ON b.headuid = c.uid 
        WHERE  a.ordate BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31' 
               AND a.brcode = '010' 
        GROUP  BY b.paytype 
        ORDER  BY b.paytype ASC)tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

//You can try this.

```
SELECT  b.paytype, CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(SUM(b.principal) AS money), 1) as Cash_sale
into #tblfirstsum FROM fin_tbl_crjhead  a 
INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjlot b 
    ON a.uid = b.headuid
left JOIN fin_tbl_crjsundries c ON b.headuid = c.uid
WHERE a.ordate BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31'
  AND a.brcode = '010'
GROUP BY b.paytype
ORDER BY b.paytype ASC
```

//Second Query

```
SELECT SUM(a.credit) as credit
 into #tblsecondSum FROM [TFINANCE].[dbo].[fin_tbl_crjsundries] a INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjlot b 
on a.headuid = b.headuid INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjhead c ON c.uid = b.headuid
  where a.acctcode = '100 200-02' and a.brcode = '010' and c.ordate
 between '2018-12-01' and '2018-12-31'


Create table #tblFinal(paytype nvarchar(100),Total_Sum double(18,6))
insert into #tblFinal (paytype,Total_Sum)
select paytype,Cash_sale from #tblfirstsum where paytype='fp' union all
select paytype,Cash_sale from #tblfirstsum where paytype='installment' union all
select 'Credit Amount',credit from #tblsecondSum

select paytype,Total_Sum from #tblFinal 
select Total=Sum(Total_Sum) from #tblFinal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UNION and SUM from the subquery as below.

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE([Cash Sales],0)) FROM 
 (
  SELECT  b.paytype AS paytype, CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(SUM(b.principal) AS money), 1) 
  as [Cash Sales]
  FROM fin_tbl_crjhead  a 
  INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjlot b 
  ON a.uid = b.headuid
  left JOIN fin_tbl_crjsundries c ON b.headuid = c.uid
  WHERE a.ordate BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31'
   AND a.brcode = '010'
  GROUP BY b.paytype

  UNION

  SELECT 'credit' AS paytype, SUM(a.credit) AS [Cash Sales]
  FROM [TFINANCE].[dbo].[fin_tbl_crjsundries] a INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjlot b 
  on a.headuid = b.headuid INNER JOIN fin_tbl_crjhead c ON c.uid = b.headuid
  where a.acctcode = '100 200-02' and a.brcode = '010' and c.ordate
  between '2018-12-01' and '2018-12-31') S
WHERE S.paytype IN  ('fp', 'installment', 'credit')
```